# How to keep observable alive after error in RxJS 6 and Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

Can anyone help with the scenario where `this._getReactions$.next()` not working whenever `this.http.get(...)` gets an error. I want to keep observable alive to take the next input.

```js
private _getReactions$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

 constructor() {
  this._getReactions$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(...)
        // http request 
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return empty();
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      //results handling
  });
 }
```

```js
onClick() {
  this._getReactions$.next();
}
```

Comment: Stackblitz please as it will be "alive".

Comment: What about https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3870#issuecomment-274227786 ?

Comment: Hi @Kansen, it's working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If observable dies it calls it error handler and they are closed you can't send anything through them that means they are closed everything upstream from that including the interval is dead.

> what if we want to live.

*sheilding the main observer chain is the solution*

*put catch inside of `switchmap`*
whenever a request is fired `switchmap` 
creates the ajax observable and this time with the
`catch`.
`switchmap` has a behavior that it says my source
is not completed yet so I don't really care if the child
completes I gonna keep going.

```
 constructor() {
  this._getReactions$
    .pipe(tap(value => { this.loading = true; return value }),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(...).pipe(
          catchError((error) => this.handleError(error)))
        // http request
      }),
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      //results handling
      this.error = false;
      this.loading = false
    });
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

  this.error = true;
  console.log(error)
  this.loading = false
  return empty();
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isolate-observable-chain)**

**[`Detailed Info`](https://medium.com/@erVikas1/how-to-keep-an-observable-returned-by-httpclient-alive-after-error-da6c5e601e9c)**

PS: nesting within any `flattening` operator, such as `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, `exhaustMap` and other flattening operators would also work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was not able to access `this.loading` inside `handleError` method. Can you help me with that?
`  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    } else {
        this.loading = false;
        this.error = true;
    }
    return empty();
  }`

Comment: @Krish i have updated my answer as well the stackblitz kindly check it:)

Comment: You can use the mechanism showed by @Vikas in your HttpInterceptor (HttpClient) to avoid duplicate code in your components and/or services.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a way to fix this for **all the request**

Create a loader file where all request will be executed

loader.ts

```
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Loader<T1, T> {
  private _requestQueue: Subject<T1>;
  private _errorQueue: Subject<Error>;
  private _resultQueue: Observable<T>;
  private _loaded = false;

  constructor(loaderFunction: (T1) => Observable<T>) {
    this._requestQueue = new Subject<T1>();
    this._errorQueue = new Subject<Error>();
    this._resultQueue = this._requestQueue.pipe(
      switchMap(_ => {
        this._loaded = false;
        return loaderFunction(_).pipe(
          catchError(error => {
            this._loaded = true;
            this._errorQueue.next(error);
            // Returning EMPTY observable won't complete the stream
            return EMPTY;
          })
        );
      }),
      map(_ => {
        this._loaded = true;
        return _;
      }),
    );
  }

  public load(arg?: T1): void {
    this._requestQueue.next(arg);
  }

  public subscribe(successFn: (T) => any, errorFn?: (error: any) => void, 
    completeFn?: () => void): Subscription {
    
    this._errorQueue.subscribe(err => {
      errorFn(err);
    });
    return this._resultQueue.subscribe(successFn, null, completeFn);
  }

  public complete() {
    this._requestQueue.complete();
    this._errorQueue.complete();
  }
  
  get loaded(): boolean {
    return this._loaded;
  }
}
```

In other files where you will be executing the requests (Easy)

```
export class Component {
  readonly loader: Loader<ResponseType, RequestParamType>;

  constructor() {
    this.loader = new Loader(param => this.http.get(param));
    this.loader.subscribe(res => {
      // Your stuffs
    }, (error) => { 
      // Error Handling stuffs
    }, () => {
      // on Complete stuffs (Optional)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() { // Call this function whenever you want to refresh the data
    this.loader.load(params); // this param will directly passed to the http request
  }
}
```

I have defined other params in the loader, which can help you like loading status and option to complete the stream (in ngOnDestroy)

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this scenario,it works for me perfectly

```
 private _getReactions$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

 constructor() {
  this.init();
 }
 private init(){
   this._getReactions$
   .pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(...)
        // http request 
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      //results handling
  }, () => this.init());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above, a nice solution would be to catch an error **INSIDE** the `switchMap()` call:

```
switchMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(...).pipe(
          catchError((error) => this.handleError(error)))
      }),
```

However, if your `pipe()` operator has many `switchMap()` calls, and thus an error might be received in multiple cases, the best solution would be to subscribe again.

For example:

```
void subscribeData(): void {
    data.pipe(
        tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get(...).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // lot of copy-paste logic
            })
        )),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get(...).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // lot of copy-paste logic
            })
        )),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get(...).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // lot of copy-paste logic
            })
        )),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get(...).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // lot of copy-paste logic
            })
        )),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get(...).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // lot of copy-paste logic
            })
        )),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get(...).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // lot of copy-paste logic
            })
        )),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get(...).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // lot of copy-paste logic
            })
        )),
        tap(() => this.isLoading = false, () => this.isLoading = false),
        takeUntil(this.destroy)
    ).subscribe(data => {...})
    );
```

You don't need to have the `catchError(...)` and copy-paste the same logic for each time. The simpler solution would be to subscribe again on the `(error) => {...}` callback in the `subcribe(...)` call:

```
void subscribeData(): void {

        data.pipe(
            tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            switchMap(() => this.http.get(...)),
            tap(() => this.isLoading = false, () => this.isLoading = false),
            takeUntil(this.destroy)
         ).subscribe(data => {...}, err => {
            //some other logic

            // subscribe again
            this.subscribeData();   // <--- subscribe again 
         });
    }
```