# Angular interceptor: Keep the stream alive after error is thrown

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, interceptor

I have an interceptor to handle errors in my Angular app.
Also I have an input that has a *keyup* function that makes API calls.

**My problem** is that when the error is throw to the component the stream is stopped (normal behaviour because of onError in subscribe), so the *keyup* function doesn't work anymore.

**My question** is how can I manage this, so it doesn't end the stream when an error is thrown to the component ?

**INTERCEPTOR :**

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMsg = ''
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          console.log('this is client side error')
          errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`
        }
        else {
          console.log('this is server side error')
          errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`
        }
        console.log(errorMsg)
        return throwError(errorMsg)
      }),
    )
  }
}
```

**SERVICE :**

```
search_address(query: string): Observable<Feature[]> {
  const url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places2/'
  return this.http.get<MapboxOutput>(url + query + '.json?limit=5&types=address&access_token=' + environment.mapboxToken).pipe(map((res: MapboxOutput) => {
    return res.features
  }))
}
```

**COMPONENT :**

```
ngOnInit() {
  // when keyup in input, trigger mapbox service to get addresses
  this.inputChanged.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged(), mergeMap((searchTerm) => this.mapboxService.search_address(searchTerm)))
  .subscribe((features: Feature[]) => {
    this.addresses = features
  }, err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use switchMap and handle the error in the inner observable so your observable chain won't die.

A more complete answer is here: [How to keep observable alive after error in RxJS 6 and Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370506/how-to-keep-observable-alive-after-error-in-rxjs-6-and-angular-6)

Comment: I have already seen this one but I don't what to return to the component because the Interceptor needs to return Observable<HttpEvent<any>>

Comment: You can have multiple return value Observable<httpevent<any>> | Observable<MyErrorType> and return of(myError) in the error condition and catchError on search_address not subscribe as if you get to err on subscribe you are done.

Comment: Can you edit your response and show how it can be done ? Even though I understand the theory, I can't make it work. Thank you

Comment: because you can't return Observable<httpevent<any>> | Observable<MyErrorType>. The intercept method is "locked" because the class implements HttpInterceptor @Wild Bill